# Conda/Anaconda looking for packages in directory that doesn't exist

Tags: python, path, anaconda, sublimetext3, conda

I am using Anaconda installed on Windows 10. Recently I started running into a DLL loading error when I tried to call numpy (and sometimes sklearn):

```
   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py",
 line 22, in <module>
     from . import multiarray   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py",
 line 12, in <module>
     from . import overrides   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py",
 line 7, in <module>
     from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

For NumPy, at least, I don't run into this issue if using jupyter notebook, started from anaconda prompt. If I tried to use another interpreter (like sublime or vs code using their conda extensions) that has been configured to look for the anaconda installation of Python, I get this error.

The thing is, "\Anaconda3\lib" doesn't exist on my machine, because on Windows, the libraries are installed in "\Anaconda3\Lib". So I have no idea why python is looking for packages in a folder that doesn't exist. In jupyter notebook (opened via anaconda prompt), the directory for packages also points to the "lib" folder, even though in that environment it doesn't seem to be a problem.

I tried starting a new environment in conda, and it still has the same issue. If anyone can explain what's going on here, I would greatly appreciate it. Is this a PATH addition issue (I didn't add an anaconda path to windows, since it's recommended by the anaconda installer)?

Comment: Typically these numpy dll errors occur when you don't activate your environment. And don't put Anaconda's Python on the path.

Comment: Windows paths are case-insensitive, so `C:\Anaconda3\Lib` and `c:\anaconda3\lib` (and all other variations) will point to exactly the same place.